# Spark Dataset with Kryo encoder how to decode back?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have result of the calculation in form of `Dataset[Either[String, MyClass]]`. For that to work I specified encoder like this: `implicit val eitherEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Either[String, MyClass]]`

The problem is: when I do `df.show(5)` I see something like this:

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[01 00 D4 01 63 6...|
|[01 00 D4 01 63 6...|
+--------------------+
```

And I can't do anything with this DF anymore. How can I decode this back?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one shouldn't use Kryo encoders with Dataset and use inbuilt Encoders.They are even more performant than Kryo.